# showing battery usage in VIM statusbar

Tags: vim, statusbar

I have a Macbook 10.7. 
I always maximize the terminal window so if I wanna check the battery status i have to move the mouse to the top or quit the maximum vim window.
So I would like to show the battery in the vim statusbar.
Here is what I did:
Create a file and make it executable.

```
vi /bin/battery

#!/bin/bash
ioreg -l|grep -i capacity | tr '\n' ' | '|awk '{printf("%.1f%%", $10/$5 * 100)}'
```

Now if I type "battery" in terminal it will output something like 87.6%.
My question is how am I supposed to show this thing in VIM status bar?

**OK! Thanks for Romainl and Ingo's help. after reading and testing i think i get a 'perfect' solution. at least i am satified. :P**

Here is the detail.

```
sudo vi /bin/battery

#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ioreg -l|grep -i capacity|tr '\n' ' | '|awk '{printf("%d%%",$10/$5*100)}'>~/.battery

crontab -e
#check battery every 4 mins.
*/4 * * * * /bin/battery
```

the battery script outputs to a file. and it runs every 4 mins(controlled by crontab).
the rest part is about the same as Ingo's answer.

```
:let g:battery = '???'
:autocmd CursorHold * let g:battery = system('cat ~/.battery')
:set statusline+=%{g:battery}
```

Comment: After a bit of experimentation it seems that `ioreg -n AppleSmartBattery -r|grep -i -e'\(max\|current\)capacity'|tr '\n' ' '|awk '{ printf("%d%%"),$6/$3 * 100 }'` should run *significantly* faster than your current command.  Not a huge deal given that you're using a cron job but figured I'd let you know.

Comment: Calculating the capacity with full capacity won't give a correct percentage, since the amount of capacity the battery can hold will vary after some usage. I'm on 100% right now, and when I execute your command, it gives me 95%, since my battery has wear down a bit.

`pmset -g batt | grep 'Internal' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-4`
Try this one. It should print the percentage correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The statusline will be updated very often (on every move!), that's too often for invoking an external script.

Have a look at `:help autocommand-events`, and use `:autocmd`s to update a Vim variable, then just include that variable in the statusline. Suitable events may be: `CursorHold`, `FocusGained`, `BufRead`

```
:let g:battery = '???'
:autocmd CursorHold * let g:battery = system('/bin/battery')
:set statusline+=%{g:battery}
```

(And/or define a mapping to update the variable manually.)

Comment: very useful! thanks a lot. I will post a perfect solution combining your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your script doesn't output anything on my MacPro but I guess that's somewhat normal (no battery).

Anyway, this should work:

```
:set statusline+=%{system('/bin/battery')}
```

Be aware that the statusline is updated very often: `/bin/battery` will probably be called a dozen times per second. It doesn't sound good for your battery!

Did you consider setting up a notification system (with Growl, for example) instead?

Or simply a custom mapping:

```
:nnoremap <F11> :exec('echo(sytem("date"))')<CR>
```

Comment: It works! But a new problem shows up...The battery script runs a bit slow so when I keep pressing a key down(such as an arrow key) it shows some stupid chars in the vi window. You can see the similar result if you change the battery script to "`sleep 1`".

Comment: so I guess your 2nd way would be easier instead of changing the battery script to make it run fast or less frequency. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that's why I proposed alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to set a cronjob and put the battery level in a file then read that file from vim.